# Why is it saying my variable is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, list

I sometimes get this error (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable) when I call getLink()[0], and I sometimes don't. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? getLink() should be subscriptable...

```
def getLink():
        for link in getElements():
            if "orgs" in link:
                return ['orgs', link]
            elif "pac" in link and "summary" in link:
                return ['pac', link]
            elif "federal-lobbying" in link and "summary" in link:
                return ['fl', link]
            else:
                return 'error'

    # get elements
    if getLink()[0] == "orgs":
```

EDIT: my issue was I needed a longer time.sleep() waiting function to give my page time to load to feed data into getElements(), sometimes it loaded fast enough and sometimes not. Thanks all!

Comment: Does ``getElements`` always yield at least one element? What *exactly* is the error message – is it by any chance ``TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable``?

Comment: Your function returns any one of `list`, `str`, or `None`. Only the `list` and `str` can be indexed into with `[0]`

Comment: If `getElements()` returns an empty iterable, then `getLink` returns `None`.

Comment: And you are unlikely to care about `'error'[0]`; if there's an error, raise an exception instead of returning a string.

Comment: And, what's the point of iterating if you are going to return something no matter what the first value of `link` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
def getLink():
        elements = getElements()
        if not elements:
                return ["error"]

        for link in elements:
            if "orgs" in link:
                return ['orgs', link]
            elif "pac" in link and "summary" in link:
                return ['pac', link]
            elif "federal-lobbying" in link and "summary" in link:
                return ['fl', link]
            else:
                return ['error']
link = getLink()
# get elements
if link[0] == "orgs":
```

as CherryDT Explained the issue is with `getElements()` if `getElements()` returns `None` then your `getLink()` function also returns `None` to solve this you will have to add a guard that checks what `getElements()` returns

Comment: `if len(elements) == 0` -> `if not elements`

Answer (score 0):

You need to trace back one step further. If `getElements()` returns an empty list, `getLink` doesn't return anything, i.e. 'None'. The problem is `getElements`, not `getLink`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `None` isn't subscriptable, which is what you return when `getElements()` returns an empty list and your loop body never executes.

(The whole `for` is misleading because you only ever look at the first item anyway because there is no code path without a `return` in the loop body.)